# Read file in EventMachine asynchronously

Tags: ruby, file, asynchronous, cassandra, eventmachine

I'm playing with Ruby EventMachines for some time now and I think I'm understandings its basics.

However, I am not sure how to read in a large file (120 MB) performantly. My goal is to read a file line by line and write every line into a Cassandra database (same should be with MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB etc. because the Cassandra client supports EM explicitly). The simple snippet blocks the reactor, right?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cassandra'
require 'thrift_client/event_machine'

EM.run do
  Fiber.new do
    rm = Cassandra.new('RankMetrics', "127.0.0.1:9160", :transport => Thrift::EventMachineTransport, :transport_wrapper => nil)
    rm.clear_keyspace!
    begin
      file = File.new("us_100000.txt", "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
      rm.insert(:Domains, "#{line.downcase}", {'domain' => "#{line}"})
    end
      file.close
    rescue => err
      puts "Exception: #{err}"
      err
    end
    EM.stop
  end.resume
end
```

But what's the right way to get a file read asynchronously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to read files in an EventMachine-based app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749503/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-files-in-an-eventmachine-based-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no asynchronous file IO support in EventMachine, the best way to achieve what you're trying to do is to read a couple of lines on each tick and send them off to the database. The most important is to not read too large chunks since that would block the reactor.

```
EM.run do
  io = File.open('path/to/file')
  read_chunk = proc do
    lines_sent = 10
    10.times do
      if line = io.gets
        send_to_db(line) do
          # when the DB call is done
          lines_sent -= 1
          EM.next_tick(read_chunk) if lines_sent == 0
        end
      else
        EM.stop
      end
    end
  end
  EM.next_tick(read_chunk)
end
```

See [What is the best way to read files in an EventMachine-based app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749503/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-files-in-an-eventmachine-based-app)

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt response ;-) Didnt know there's no way for async filesystem I/O before, so thanks for the hint. On the other hand I tried your snippet: http://pastie.org/2696497. But i got a new error in this case: http://pastie.org/2696500. The Cassandra client is EM aware.

Comment: I have no idea what causes that error, but I changed two details about my example: it needs to wait for the DB call to return (yield, actually) before reading the next chunk, and also wait for all the ten lines...

Comment: Hm, still some trouble with the async reading of files. It seems the send_to_db call blocks the reactor. Maybe its the same what you mean with "wait for the DB call to return"? Do you have a code snippet what exactley you changed?

Comment: You must replace `send_to_db` with a call to your DB driver. If your DB driver is asynchronous it must have some way to specify a callback, in that callback do the thing in the block.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you might take a look at [EM::FileStreamer](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/streamer.rb). For one thing, FileStreamer uses a C++ based 'fast file reader'. Couldn't you stream the file over a local socket/pipe and handle the sending to db in a separate process that's listening on the other end?

Also there is a non-Fiber based example of handling sync db connections gracefully in [ThreadedResource](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/threaded_resource.rb), in case that's helpful...specifically mentions Cassandra. Although it sounds like your Cassandra library is Fiber based.